# Insert picture/logo at a specific position

Tags: positioning, diagrams

Im using the MastersDoctoralThesis [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

and i want to add a logo of my university on the title page. I marked the desired position of the logo with a black dot, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

The logo should not change the position of text.

Comment: You can use Ti*k*Z `remember picture,overlay`

Comment: From this short tutorial https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package it looks like TikZ can be used to draw diagrams. I just want to a picture.png

Comment: Yes. Although TikZ can be used to draw diagrams, that is not its only feature.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and preconvert the PNG to PDF, PNG takes some time to be included into a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with `eso-pic`. You can put pictures in the background of the page. With `\AddToShipoutBG*` you add something to the next page that is shipped out, and with `\put` you can put stuff at arbitrary places inside the argument of `\AddToShipoutBG*`.

(in the following I use `report`, but it should also work with MastersDoctoralThesis)

```latex
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*
  {%
    \put(\LenToUnit{.6\paperwidth}, \LenToUnit{.8\paperheight})
      {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}%
  }


\usepackage{duckuments}% dummy content for following pages

\begin{document}
\author{Someone}
\title{Something}
\date{Somewhen}

\maketitle

\duckument
\end{document}
```

Resulting title page:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ti*k*Z's `remember picture,overlay`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vspace*{10cm}
  {\huge Your title page here}

  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \path (current page.north east) ++ (-5,-3) node {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great choice of example picture!